# Log to different server with same password and username from xpage

Tags: xpages, credentials

I have 2 servers. One with mail (server:webmail.test.com, path: mailErmo.nsf). And another with xpage (server: xpage.example.com, path:testXpage.xsp).

Im trying to open webmail in iframe or in new tab from xpages. Username and password are the same on both pages.

Edit:

I need to reenter username/password. Want xpage to do this for me.

Comment: It is rather server configuration problem - look for SSO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really isn't an XPages question. Its more of a server question. What you want to set up is single sign on for multiple servers. Once you authenticate against server #1 you will receive a token / cookie that will allow you to be authenticated against server #2 as well.

Now, granted, you actually can send credentials to the server to authenticate the user fro them, but it is bad design, as you would have to get / store the password (even if you are just storing in ram) which is insecure.

Use the pre-defined methods given to you by domino to accomplish (multiple server SSO).

Comment: Also depending on what they are doing, they may need to update the "Trusted Server" field in related server documents.

Comment: Would be interesting to port Shiboleh to Domino